# Drawing three surfaces and a bunch of points which need to be placed between the surfaces

Tags: graphics, pstricks, pst-solides3d

I want to draw three surfaces, which are kind of parallel with each other, and a bunch of points. Some of these points will be placed in the region between the most external surfaces and others will be placed outside this region. Here is a primitive sketch of what I want.

[image]

Using the `pst-solides3d` package and help of the post [post](http://tusex.stackexchange.com/questions/173191/making-mesh-grid-lines-transparent-in-surface-plot-with-pgfplots) I reached at the following drawing.

[image]

Its quality is great, but it still not passing with clarity the points that are between the most external surfaces (the red ones) and the points that are out of them. From this I would appreciate some help with:

- (Main question) How can I manage the visual efects of the points in the way that one can easily discern between the points that are in and out of the most external surfaces.
- (Bonus quation) How can I draw orthogonal lines that goes from the points to the middle surface (blue).

The code from the draw is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\psset{viewpoint=35 20 15 rtp2xyz,Decran=160,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-2)(3.5,3)
\axesIIID(1,1,1)(3,2,2)

\psSurface[opacity=0.6,strokeopacity=0.4,fillcolor=red!80,linecolor=black!20,
           linewidth=0.4pt,algebraic,ngrid=0.2 0.2,
           Zmin=0,Zmax=2,showAxes=false](-1,-1)(1,1){0.25*e^(-x^2-y^2)}
           
\psSurface[opacity=0.6,strokeopacity=0.4,fillcolor=blue!80,linecolor=black!20,
           linewidth=0.2pt,algebraic,ngrid=0.2 0.2,
           Zmin=0,Zmax=2,showAxes=false](-1,-1)(1,1){0.25*e^(-x^2-y^2)+0.5}
           
\psSurface[opacity=0.6,strokeopacity=0.4,fillcolor=red!80,linecolor=black!20,
           linewidth=0.2pt,algebraic,ngrid=0.2 0.2,axesboxed,
           Zmin=0,Zmax=2,showAxes=false](-1,-1)(1,1){0.25*e^(-x^2-y^2)+1}
           
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0 0 1]%      
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0 0.5 1]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.5 0 1]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.5 0.5 1]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0 0.25 0.8]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.35 0 1]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0 0.45 0.7]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0.15 1]%   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.7 0.7 1]%   

\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 0 0.5]%     
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 -0.15 0.5]%     
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=-1 0 0.5]%     
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0 -0.15 0.3]%     
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 0.5 0.1]%     
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0 0.2]%     

\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0 0.1]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0.3 0.2]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 0.15 -0.1]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 -0.6 0.0]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 0 0.1]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.0 0 -0.2]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0.15 -0.15]% 
   
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0 1.3]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0.3 1.2]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 0.15 1.6]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 -0.6 1.5]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=1 0 0.2]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.0 0 1.4]% 
\psSolid[object=point,fillcolor=yellow,
args=0.15 0.15 2]%            
\end{pspicture}
\caption{teste}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```